# Match only list of words in string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a list of words and am creating a regular expression like so:

```
((word1)|(word2)|(word3){1,3})
```

Basically I want to match a string that contains 1 - 3 of those words.

This works, however I want it to match the string *only* if the string contains words from the regex. For example:

```
((investment)|(property)|(something)|(else){1,3})
```

This should match the string `investmentproperty` but not the string `abcinvestmentproperty`. Likewise it should match `somethinginvestmentproperty` because all those words are in the regex.

How do I go about achieving that?

Thanks

Comment: `{1, 3}` should be `{1,3}` without the space. And it only applies to `(word3)`. You need `((word1)|(word2)|(word3)){1,3}`. Also it’s better to avoid capturing groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$...^` to match with a string with (`^`) and (`$`) to mark the beginning and ending of the string you want to match. Also note you need to add `(...)` around your group of words to match for the `{1,3}`:

```
^((investment)|(property)|(something)|(else)){1,3}$
```

[*Regex101 Example*](https://regex101.com/r/vYFlUY/2)

Comment: Additionally, I would add non-capturing groups: `^(?:(investment)|(property)|(something)|(else)){1,3}$`. To OP: you'll also need the `multiline` flag for sthis to work in a multiline string.